# Did Yoda, Obi-Wan, and Anakin eventually dissipate?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi

At the end of *Return of the Jedi* we're shown that Anakin, Yoda, and Obi-Wan are Force ghosts.

At that time they were one with the Force, their living energy had been returned to it, but they were able to maintain their consciousness and appear to Luke.

My question is: over time, did they eventually "die" properly, dissipating and returning fully to the Force?

I'm looking for references from canon or the EU, legends, etc.

> NB: it's been hinted that Obi-wans ghost may appear in Episode 8, but as yet this is not official.

Answer (score 3):

### No

Force Ghosts or Force Spirits (as they are now called in Canon), are described as being immortal. Or rather, becoming a force ghost is a method of achieving immortality.

From the script:

> **YODA:** Master Kenobi, wait a moment. In your solitude on Tatooine,
> training I have for you.
> **OBI-WAN KENOBI:** Training?
> **YODA:** An old
> friend has learned the path to immortality.
> **OBI-WAN KENOBI:** Who?
> **YODA:** One who has returned from the netherworld of the Force to train
> me... your old Master, Qui-Gon Jinn.
>
> *[Episode III: The Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith)*

Now, to say that they *can't* dissipate/die/move on, would probably be incorrect. However, we do not know for sure one way or the other. But it is definitely not something that happens automatically. They can continue existing for at least as long as they want.

Comment: Originally in legends it was suggested they could only be force ghosts temporarily (as Obi-Wan explains to Luke early in Heir to the Empire, telling Luke it will be the last time they meet) of course that was before the prequel trilogy and was eventually retconned.